# Loop não executa no Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Estou tentando executar um `loop` no *Xcode*, porém ele não funciona.

**No console fica:**

> Digite o numero do loop:
>   5

Não acontece mais nada no terminal. Não aparece o 0,1,2,3,4,5.

Resumindo, ele fica parado depois que eu digito qualquer número, porém, pelo que eu vi, ainda está em execução, eu tenho que dar um stop para poder executar novamente.

**O debug session:**

Coloquei um breakpoint nas variáveis e dei um stepover

[image: deub]

Isso tem a ver com o `@autoreleasepool`? O mesmo acontece com o meu `switch`.

**Meu código**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
     @autoreleasepool {
        int i, usuario;
        NSLog(@"Digite o numero do loop: ");
        scanf("%i", &usuario);
        for (i=0; i<=usuario; i++) {
             NSLog(@"%i", i);
        }        
     }
 return 0;
}
```

O projeto foi criado em Foundation, Command Line Tool.

Comment: Adicionado mais algumas informações.

Comment: Acrescentei o que faltava.

Comment: Quando o debugger estiver parado na linha do `scanf()`, tecle F6 (Step Over). Nesse momento, o `scanf()` é executado e você deve digitar um número seguido da tecla Return. Após isso, o debugger deve passar para a próxima linha, a que contém o `for`. No seu caso, o que ocorre exatamente em cada um desses passos?

Comment: Pois bem, o debugger fica marcado na linha do scanf, com um (lldb) no final do console, quando eu aperto F6, a linha que marca o debugger some, assim como o (lldb), então eu digito qualquer número e dou enter, porém mais nada acontece, parece que nem entra no for...

Answer (score 1):

Tem a certeza que não computa o loop?

Penso que o erro está em ter a variàvel `"%i"` que penso que deveria ser apenas `"%d"` ou então `"%f"` para float:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
     @autoreleasepool {
        int i, usuario;
        NSLog(@"Digite o numero do loop: ");
        scanf("%d", &usuario);
        for (i=0; i<=usuario; i++) {
             NSLog(@"%d", i);
        }        
     }
 return 0;
}
```

De qualquer forma aconselhor a por printf's ao longo do troço de código.

Cumprimentos.

Comment: Continua o mesmo problema. Adicionei mais algumas informações.